# Hash function and combining multiple keys

Tags: hash

I have three keys (two strings and one integer) in each element and I want to design a hash function. To make the hashtable uniform I want to use all three keys. What path should I follow?

```
private:
    string name; 
    int age;        
    string homeTown;
```

Comment: This is missing a lot of context: language, size of strings, distribution of strings / integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most naive implementation would use a sum of keys per field like so:

```
return fieldA.getHashCode() + fieldB.getHashCode() + fieldC.getHashCode();
```

I use this approach most of the time. However this is not the most optimal design due to the fact that key cardinality really has influence on the "most unique" behavior. The design goal for hash keys is simple - to get the most unique representation of object data with a few bytes, so really if "fieldA" has more logical weight then you better use some kind of polynomial formula like:

```
 a^2 + b*2 + c //where a,b,c are hashes of fields
```

OR

```
 a^3 + b^2 + c ^1
```

The exponential part yields better result than linear summation because it assigns different weight to position, so in case 2nd and 3rd field yield the same hash the result will still be different.

```
10 + 2 + 18 = 18 + 10 + 2
```

BUT

```
10^3 + 2^2 + 18 != 18^3 + 10^2 + 2
```

The proper design of hash functions is really not a simple topic and involves probability theory.

Comment: so where can I find an algorithm about this? The all algorithms are designed with one key.

Comment: If speed is of no issue then use: a^3 + b^2 + c How many records/entities do you plan to have? And how often do you plan to get them in/out hashtables? If you have a list of people then just use their SSN. I'd give you better advice if I see your class declaration code (fieldnames to infer their meaning/possible distribution)

Comment: Actually speed is very important. About 2000 entry. Actually this is an homework and they are going to grade the homework by its speed and uniformity. I edited the question.

Comment: Then use this:  name.getHash()*1000 + homeTown.getHash()*10 + age.getHash(). And make sure that this operation is unchecked for overflow